# Relationship between dispersion statistic and variance in count data models?

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, count-data, poisson-regression, overdispersion

I am struggling to get my head around the concept of data dispersion, particularly relating to count models.

Take for example, the Poisson regression model, I will often read that if the variance of the response variable is significantly greater than the mean of the response variable, the data is overdispersed, and a simple Poisson regression model is probably not appropriate.

I will then read, however, than one of the potential solutions to overdispersion is to include additional significant predictors in the model or include a significant interaction term.
How does including an additional significant potentially reduce the variance of the response variable? Obviously it doesn’t, but I’m struggling to identify the flaw in my thinking.

Further, I researched one of the methods for calculating the dispersion statistic, which should equal 1 in a equidispersed model (and > 1 in an overdispersed model). The basic formula is:

```
(Sum of squared Pearson residuals)/(Residual degrees of freedom)
```

So here I can see how including a significant predictor would reduce the residuals, and consequently reduce the dispersion statistic. But how does that tie back to the variance in the response variable?